# How to Post data to database and Bind it to web-grid in same view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am new to MVC and I am tring to create a ***'Registration-Form'*** in MVC4.

1. I have created a ***'Registration-Form'*** which adds data to database Table ***'Registration'*** on click of submit.
2. I have a ***'Web-Grid'*** on same page just below the ***'Registration-Form'*** which displays the data present in database table ***'Registration'***.

Both operation works fine in different views.
But when I am trying to implement in one view there is a problem.

1st operation need normal model variable.

2nd operation need IEnumerable model variable.

How can I resolve this problem.

Here is my code:

> Controller:

```
    namespace RegistrationMVC.Controllers
    {
    public class RegistrationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Registration/

        public ActionResult Index(Registration model)
        {
            UserContext dbContext = new UserContext();
            var details = dbContext.Registration.ToList();
            return View(details);
        }
        public enum Command
        {
            Create,
            Reset
        }

         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Registration model, Command command)
        {
            if (command == Command.Create)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    UserContext dbContext = new UserContext();

                    var newRegistration = new Registration() { Email = model.Email, Password = model.Password, FName = model.FName, LName = model.LName, Contact = model.Contact, Address = model.Address };
                    dbContext.Registration.Add(newRegistration);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

> Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<RegistrationMVC.Models.Registration>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_NewRegistration")
    @grid.GetHtml()
</body>
</html>
```

> Registration Partial View:

```
@model RegistrationMVC.Models.Registration

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Registration Failed. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration</legend>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, "Email:")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            <br />

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, "Password:")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            <br />

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName, "First Name:")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName)
            <br />

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName, "Last Name:")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName)
            <br />

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact, "Contact No:")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact)
            <br />

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, "Address:")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            <br />

            <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Create" />
            <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Reset" />

    </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you using ajax at all?

Comment: No using controller only.

Comment: I can't really tell from your question if what you need is: 1. to display the newly submitted registration in the gridview without refreshing the page, or 2. to submit the new registration, refresh the page (i.e., do a POST) and then the gridview will show the new registration. Main difference is that for #1 you would need AJAX and highly recommend knockout and #2 you just need to adjust the model (probably create a viewmodel) that gets returned after the POST.

Answer (score 0):

I have Using partial Views and providing Model as needed to the specific partial view